# About apis, on which technology I have to made apis if I am developing application in react native?

Tags: api, react-native, mobile, mobile-application

I am developing one application in react native I am new to it.  So curious to know that on which platform api should be build?

Thanks

Comment: The only requirement, if it must be accessible from a browser client, is that it can communicate over the HTTP protocol. Beyond that, it's totally up to you. Using JSON as the data interchange format would be a sensible choice, but there's no need to do so. What language / server / framework etc you use to _implement_ the API software is a totally separate decision and depends on many other factors / constraints of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, there may no reason for API at all.

If you need to store data on the server then API may be build in any technology you feel comfortable with. As far as the React Native goes, it supports many ways to connect to API, including both REST and GraphQL.

Comment: thank it helps so according to you I can make api in php dot net? it will make no difference

Comment: Yep. The only thing that matters is method of data exchange, such as REST or GraphQL. Many of backend technologies support high variety of these methods.

Comment: @Xenor REST is an architectural design pattern used to inform the specification of API endpoints, not a method of data exchange. It says nothing about the format that data being exchanged must be in. GraphQL is a way of structuring data (taking advantage of the JSON data interchange format), though, so that's a slightly better example. Although as far as I can see, React Native gives you full access to the XHR interface, so in theory, just like any web app you can send and receive data to/from the server in any format you like, as long as it's done over HTTP.

Comment: yep, no arguing with that :). i've just wanted to throw some terms out there for user9282301, as his question wasnt really specific. XHR would another of those terms.